# Питон парсер видеороликов

Tags: python, парсер

пытаюсь парсить один очень интересный сайт, хочу получить ссылки на все видео со страницы, но к сожалению получаю только такой вывод, почему то не выводит код на определенное видео, пишет просто None

вот мой код:

```
url = 'http://porno365.world'
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
card = soup.find_all('li', class_='video_block')

for c in card:
    card_url = f'http://porno365.world{c.get("href")}'
    card_text = c.find('p').text.strip()

    print(card_url)
```

[image: вывод кода]

Comment: Очевидно, у элементов li не бывает никакого href

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надеюсь твои начинания помогут миру посадить деревья

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://porno365.world'
header = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'

r = requests.get(url=url, headers={'content-type': 'text', 'header': header})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
card = soup.find_all('li', class_='video_block')

for i in card:
    print([ (j['href'], j.getText()[1:]) for j in i.find_all('a', href=True)])
```

`[('http://***.world/movie/29149', 'Принес пиццу Иден Айви и соблазнил за деньги')]`